# Can I use AdSense in a CapacitorJS application to show ads across all 3 platforms: Web, iOS and Android?

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, adsense, capacitor

**Background**

I have an app that's available on the web, iOS and Android.

I’m using CapacitorJS, Angular and Firebase as main tech stack. By using Capacitor I have a single codebase for all 3 platforms.

How Capacitor works on iOS and Android is that it takes your web-projects dist-folder and wraps it in a native WebView. Sort of like how Ionic works. And this is what makes showing ads tricky.

**Problem/Question**

I would like to use one single ad provider across all 3 platforms. From my understanding AdSense is only to be used on websites while AdMob is used on mobile apps.

BUT, my whole app is web based, even the ios/android app is just the website shown in a webview. Doesn't this mean I could use AdSense even in my mobile apps, or are there any restrictions I'm unaware of?

How would you handle my scenario? What options do I have? I appreciate any suggestions or insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/48182?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841#zippy=%2Cview-full-ad-placement-policies

**Google ads, search boxes or search results may not be:**

**Integrated into a software application (does not apply to AdMob) of any kind, including toolbars.**

1. So to answer your question adsense cannot be used in any software application ( does not apply to Admob). So you can use it in native android and ios app.
2. Also refer to https://support.google.com/admob/answer/48182?hl=en ( Refer Technical requirements section ) You need to check what type of adsense ads you are using within the app.

WebView

AdSense for content (AFC) and Ad Exchange (AdX) display ads are not supported through all WebView technologies.

**App developers wishing to monetize by publishing AFC and AdX display ads through a WebView must use one of the following supported viewing frames:**

**Android:** Chrome Custom Tab

**iOS:** SFSafariViewController (iOS9 and iOS10 only)

**Google AdMob and AdX in-app ads may be shown in an app next to a WebView so long as the Google Mobile Ads SDK is in use and the publisher is compliant with all other AdSense program policies.**

3. Using a third party website within your android app also requires permission from website owner. So you might be asked to present the proof of ownership or your app might be removed from play store. Refer to admob policy for using website within your app.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860#Exceptions_AdSense&zippy=%2Cview-exceptions%2Cview-ad-placement-policies

**Displaying a third party site in your app**

When an app displays someone else's site within a frame, this is considered framing content. Publishers are not permitted to frame third party content and monetize it without permission from the owners of that content.

If a publisher owns the content, it can be framed in their app and monetized. However, if the framed content is already being monetized by Google Ads, the framed content should not contain any additional code for AdSense or AdMob inside the version on the mobile app.

4. Apple is strict on approving apps which are mimicking a website so chances of rejecting on apple are high ( not related to advertisement ) https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design
   **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn’t provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes Store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the Apple Books Store.

Displaying ads within webview doesn't give native experience to end user. So technically you are not violating any rules ( as long admob other policies are followed ). Its recommended to implement native Ads for rich UI experience