# Adsense ads inside android app Custom tab webview

Tags: admob, android-webview, adsense, android-customtabs

I have developed an android app with chrome custom webview to load [my website](https://spytm.com) which contains Adsense ads and I didn't use AdMob in my app.

I have seen the below two contradictory policies from the google policy page. My understanding is we can use Adsense ads in apps with custom tab webview but cannot place AdSense ads directly in the app. Is that correct?

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en&ref_topic=1250104#3&zippy=%2Cwhich-ad-code-should-i-put-on-web-apps-app-embedding-web-admob-or-adsense

[image]

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en#zippy=

[image]

Comment: these are not contradictory policy, but they are designed that way. Also I looked at your website and you might be asked to show proof of ownership of website while approval of the process . Didin't find any admob advertisment on your website but if you are using advertisement on your website then you can't use adsense in your app. See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714392/can-i-use-adsense-in-a-capacitorjs-application-to-show-ads-across-all-3-platform/67717473#67717473

Comment: your answer is more collapsing... You mentioned "admob advertisment on your website" which is not possible. Admob is for apps and adsense is for website. My site is adsense approved but I didn't place any ads as of now. The question is not about admob ads. Whether I can show adsense ads in my website via app with chrome custom tab webview?

Comment: sorry for that.. what i meant was Google ads / adsense for website. To make it more clear... here is content from above link "If a publisher owns the content, it can be framed in their app and monetized. However, if the framed content is already being monetized by Google Ads, the framed content should not contain any additional code for AdSense or AdMob inside the version on the mobile app."

Answer (score 0):

You can not use AdSense Ads I your app since it is a violation.. I know developers that've got their whole account suspended over this. Please do not do it.. trust me you will deeply regret it.. it is 100% a violation.